# Формула в Excel выдает 0

Tags: excel

Формула выдает нужное значение, но при нажатии энтр получаю 0, как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается нужно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.